# How to convert a chess co-ordinate into row, column for 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, chess

I'm totally stumped, and wondered if anyone knew a way to convert a user input of "a1" in chess to [][] in a 2D array?

Comment: Why not give it a try? See [askl], but coding questions should have a [mcve]. Chess coordinates are always column-row pairs, and they will always be a single character for each, for a maximum of two characters. A naive approach would be to split the coords into a column and a row, and use that as indices to a 2D array (after transforming the column and row into actual indices -- how you do that is up to you, but an easy approach is to use the row as-is, and turn the column into an index via a simple A -> 1, B -> 2 transform. Be careful with 0- vs. 1- based indices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a chess board is well defined, another approach would be to use an enum. For example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChessPosition cp = ChessPosition.valueOf("A1");
        System.out.println(cp);

        cp = ChessPosition.valueOf("H8");
        System.out.println(cp);
    }

    public enum ChessPosition {

        A1(0, 0),
        // ...
        H8(7, 7);


        private final int row;
        private final int column;

        private ChessPosition(int row, int column) {
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        public int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name() + " row=" + getRow() + ", column=" + getColumn();
        }
    }
```

Comment: very useful! thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The below code shows you how to do the transformation you need:

```
String str = "g3";
System.out.println(str.charAt(0) - 'a');
System.out.println(str.charAt(1) - '1');
```

will print

```
6
2
```

so 
`str.charAt(0) - 'a'` to transform the letter 
`str.charAt(1) - '1'` to transform the number

Comment: But how will this work for all the letters?(thanks for your response btw!)

Comment: @MarinaCalder the method `charAt(0)` returns the char at the `0`th index of the string, but when combined in an arithmetic operation like `charAt(0)-'a'` returns the ASCII code of the char. So if the the char is `'a'` then `charAt(0)-'a'->'a'-'a'->0`, if the the char is `'b'` then `charAt(0)-'a'->'b'-'a'->1`,..., if the the char is `'h'` then `charAt(0)-'a'->'h'-'a'->7`. So it works for all the letters.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this explanation!

Answer (score 4):

First, consider that character code points are arranged alphabetically. Since characters in Java are represented as unsigned integers, you could subtract the code point of `'a'` from another character to see how far it is from `'a'`: `'a'-'a' = 0`, `'b'-'a' = 1`, `'c'-'a' = 2`, and so on. Assuming that the first character of a two-character string is a lowercase letter in the a..h range, you can get your first "coordinate" like this:

```
int hPos = coord.charAt(0)-'a';
```

You can do the same thing for the digit:

```
int vPos = coord.charAt(1)-'1';
```

In addition, [Java supplies a way to extract a digit from a numeric codepoint.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int)) Since `a..h` are considered digits in base-18, you could also use this approach:

```
int hPos = Character.digit(coord.charAt(0), 18) - 10;
int vPos = Character.digit(coord.charAt(1), 10) - 1;
```

Comment: I’m trying to convert any chess co ordinate from a user input